# Automatic shutdown error within Xammp and MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am trying to start the mysql portion of xammp and i got a log issue i went into the logs and this is the error code any idea what could have gone wrong

Power cycling my system to see whether or not it was just an error
i have tried to open myphp admin to view this but i cannot due to the system being local and without mysql being opened within xammp it will not connect

Here is the log error from xammp:

```
13:32:11  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
13:32:11  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
13:32:15  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
13:32:15  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
13:32:15  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:32:15  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:32:15  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
13:32:15  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
13:32:15  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
13:32:15  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

and here is the error within the log file:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
    2019-10-29 13:32:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2019-10-29 13:32:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    2019-10-29 13:32:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
    2019-10-29 13:32:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    2019-10-29 13:32:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
    2019-10-29 13:32:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
    2019-10-29 13:32:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2019-10-29 13:32:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
    2019-10-29 13:32:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
    2019-10-29 13:32:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '\University\Year 2\Web Development\Xampp\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
    2019-10-29 13:32:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '\University\Year 2\Web Development\Xampp\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
    2019-10-29 13:32:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2019-10-29 13:32:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 14874307; transaction id 11655
    2019-10-29 13:32:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from E:\University\Year 2\Web Development\Xampp\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
    2019-10-29 13:32:14 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    2019-10-29 13:32:14 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Looks like you may already have a MySQL Server or something running on port 3306

Comment: _and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues_ Did you look at the Windows Event Viewer ___for more clues___

Comment: @RiggsFolly aye, not much help there

Comment: @RiggsFolly no help from the event manager plus the completed errors solutions did not work for me this is completely different